# how to verify emails after link is clicked usind django rest auth

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am using Django rest auth to authenticate users in my app, the users are successfully getting the email to verify their account but on clicking the link, they get an error

```
KeyError at /account-confirm-email/MTU:1iNTcO:lRoljcqAs3HQMlyy9AzUJH6Kq5w/
```

Please, how can the users be successfully verified when they click the link

my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'users',
]

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 1
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT = 5
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_TIMEOUT = 86400 # 1 day in seconds
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL ='/accounts/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/profile'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'test@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'testE'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'test@gmail.com'
DEFAULT_TO_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER

EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = '/
```

urls.py

```
from rest_auth.registration.views import VerifyEmailView


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('api/rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    url('api/account/', include('users.api.urls')),
    url('api/rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    re_path(r'^account-confirm-email/', VerifyEmailView.as_view(), name='account_email_verification_sent'),
    re_path(r'^account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', VerifyEmailView.as_view(), name='account_confirm_email'),
]
```

[update] the updated traceback after implementing the solution

```
Traceback:

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  145.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  143.                 response = response.render()

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  309.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  443.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  90.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

File "D:\Opeodedeyi\Documents\Django\WORK IN PROGRESS\ProfilesAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  673.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /account-confirm-email/MTk:1iNcyz:wyyIWJiSWJ2s9JHabdympHnzbMU/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'account_email' not found. 'account_email' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Comment: Are they accessing the URL which errors via a POST or GET request? Is it possible to see the traceback from the error?

Comment: @MattSeymour I just updated the post, putting in the traceback error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is an issue with URLs which is causing your problem. Specifically these two:

```py
re_path(r'^account-confirm-email/', VerifyEmailView.as_view(), name='account_email_verification_sent'),
re_path(r'^account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', VerifyEmailView.as_view(), name='account_confirm_email'),
```

On the first URL you are missing the `$`. Therefore the first URL is being used
for your confirmation link `/account-confirm-email/MTU:1iNTcO:lRoljcqAs3HQMlyy9AzUJH6Kq5w/` instead of the second URL which captures the regex named group `key`. Because you are falling into the first URL the regex capture group `key` is never set. Subsequently when you are in your view the `kwarg['key']` has never been set.

The solution is to change the urls to be:

```py
from rest_auth.registration.views import VerifyEmailView


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('api/rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    url('api/account/', include('users.api.urls')),
    url('api/rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),

    # note the $ symbol at the end of the regex
    re_path(r'^account-confirm-email/$', VerifyEmailView.as_view(), name='account_email_verification_sent'),
    re_path(r'^account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', VerifyEmailView.as_view(), name='account_confirm_email'),
]
```

Comment: hello, I removed the URL as advised, and I got a different error

Comment: ```NoReverseMatch at /api/rest-auth/registration/
Reverse for 'account_email_verification_sent' not found. 'account_email_verification_sent' is not a valid view function or pattern name.```

Comment: Oh sorry keep that url in there. My mistake, I have never used this library before.

Comment: sorry once again, your solution ALMOST did the trick, I faced another error and it seems i may have missed something

Comment: ```NoReverseMatch at /account-confirm-email/MTk:1iNcyz:wyyIWJiSWJ2s9JHabdympHnzbMU/
Reverse for 'account_email' not found. 'account_email' is not a valid view function or pattern name.```

Comment: Does it give you a traceback with information on where the error occurred?

Comment: It looks like all_auth is trying to load a URL for account_email. Just add all_auth urls to your urls, or add a url entry for a url with the name account_email

Comment: Did adding the url into your urls help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201385/discussion-between-matt-seymour-and-opeyemi-odedeyi).